# PHP - Obtener tiempo de respuesta de base de datos MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, date, time

Seguí [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766987/mysql-query-to-average-time) para intentar obtener el tiempo de respuesta de mi base de datos.

**La estructura de la base de datos es:**

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                                     |
|     ticketid    tecnico_id        time_at      visit_hour_in     visit_hour_out     |
|_____________________________________________________________________________________|
|        1             3             08:15            16:03            17:00          |
|        2             7             10:45            11:03            13:00          |
|        3             9             08:05            12:03            14:00          |
|        4             6             08:43            12:03            13:30          |
|        5            10             13:30            14:03            15:45          |
|_____________________________________________________________________________________|
```

`time_at`, `visit_hour_in` y `visit_hour_out` son tipo `varchar`. Entonces, me gustaría sacar el tiempo de respuesta por `tecnico_id`.

**Intenté con esta query sql:**

```
SELECT tecnico_id,
  AVG((time_at) - (visit_hour_in)) AS responseTime,
  AVG((visit_hour_in) - (visit_hour_out)) AS activityTime,
  AVG((time_at) - (visit_hour_out)) AS handlingTime
FROM `ticket` GROUP BY tecnico_id ORDER BY `ticket`.`tecnico_id` ASC
```

**Pero el resultado que arroja es este:**

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                           |
|        tecnico_id     responseTime    activityTime        handlingTime    |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
|        3                    0              0                    0         |
|        5                 13.6              0                  13.6        |
|        6      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        7      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        8      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        9      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        10     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        11     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        18     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        19     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        20     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        21     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        22     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        23     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        24     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
```

El `5.791946308724833`, `-0.37583892617449666` y `5.416107382550336` no se repiten, simplemente no quise cambiar los valores de cada uno.

Para convertir eso a horas y minutos, uso `gmdate('H:i', '5.791946308724833')`, (por ejemplo), sin embargo... Los resultados no tienen sentido *para nada*. Lo que *necesito hacer*, es sacar la diferencia entre los campos mencionados (`time_at` con `visit_hour_in`, `visit_hour_in` con `visit_hour_out` y finalmente `time_at` con `visit_hour_out`), y sacar un promedio por cada tecnico. Finalmente, un promedio *de toda la tabla* para medir el tiempo de respuesta. Un ejemplo de lo que quiero mostrar es:

> El responseTime del tecnico_id #3 es 02 hrs y 3 min, su activity time es de 0 hrs y 48 min, y su tiempo de solución por ticket (handlingTime) es de 3 horas y 0 min.

**¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?**

Comment: Pero no estas sacando un pormedio en si, ya que deberias ver la diferencia de tiemoi y la cantidad de veces que atendio el tecnico

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que no puedo hacer y aún no sé como. Si te fijas en [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11767152/11085376) de drew010, se supone que esto saca dicho promedio.
En cuanto a la cantidad de veces que el técnico ha atendido, tengo otro query que cuenta cada ticket asignado al técnico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creería que esto te podría ayudar:
1- contar la cantidad de veces que el técnico atendió,
2- ver la cantidad de tiempo que el técnico se atender los ticket
3- dividir ese tiempo el la cantidad de veces y ese seria tu promedio

```
SELECT tecnico_id, COUNT(tecnico_id) as cantidad_tecnico ,
 SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))) as tiempo, 
 (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))/COUNT(tecnico_id)) as promedio
FROM ticket group by tecnico_id asc
```

Comment: Gracias, @Igmer Rodriguez . Pero... `date_at`, `time_at`, `visit_date`, `visit_hour_in` y `visit_hour_out` son `varchar`, entonces, el resultado del query arroja algo como esto:

`tecnico_id: 3     cantidad_tecnico:  356   tiempo: NULL    promedio: NULL`

Comment: ah eso no lo sabia pense era tipo time

Comment: No. Se almacenan así:
`date_at : 2018-05-29     time_at:  16:30    visit_hour_in: 16:40   visit_hour_out: 17:30`

Comment: [Supongo que esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239010/11085376) debería funcionarme, pero no me funciona.

Comment: `SELECT tecnico_id, COUNT(tecnico_id) as cantidad_tecnico ,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,STR_TO_DATE(time_at, '%H:i'),STR_TO_DATE(visit_hour_in, '%H:i')) as tiempo,
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,STR_TO_DATE(time_at, '%H:i'),STR_TO_DATE(visit_hour_in, '%H:i'))/COUNT(tecnico_id)) as promedio
FROM ticket group by tecnico_id asc`

Intenté convertirlo así, @Igmer, pero no funcionó. ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: he actulizado mi respuesta ya que hay que convertir los string a time y la he probado y creeria que resuelve

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, @Igmer!

Comment: SQL fue uno de los temas que mas problema me dio ahora medio lo entiendo y me alegra haberte ayudado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90458/discussion-between-josue-d-marin-and-igmer-rodriguez).