# Iniciar un cronómetro a partir de hora dada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, mysqli

[Esto es en seguimiento al post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241623/php-obtener-tiempo-de-respuesta-de-base-de-datos-mysqli) que hice hace unos cuantos días para obtener el tiempo de respuesta de un técnico a un ticket.

La sección básicamente quedó de esta forma:

```
   <table class="table m-0">
   <tbody>
   <?php
      $users = array();{
          $users = TicketData::getAllPendings();              
      }
      if (count($users) > 0) {
          echo("<thead><tr><th># Ticket</th><th>Técnico</th><th>Estado</th><th>Tiempo de Respuesta</th><th>Hora de la Llamada</th></tr></thead>");
      ?>
   <?php
      foreach ($users as $user) {
         $project = $user->getProject();
         $events = TicketData::getEvents();
      ?>
   <?php $ticketStatus = $user->getStatus()->name; ?>
   <tr>
   <td><a href="index.php?view=viewticket&id=<?php echo$user->id; ?>"><?php $ticketId=$user->id; echo $ticketId; ?></a></td>
   <td><?php echo $user->getUsername()->name." ".$user->getUsername()->lastname; ?></td>
   <td>
   <?php if($ticketStatus=="En Proceso"){
      echo "<span class='badge badge-warning'>".$ticketStatus."</span>";
      }elseif ($ticketStatus=="Pendiente") {
         echo "<span class='badge badge-danger'>".$ticketStatus."</span>";
      }
      ?>
   </td>
   <td>
   <?php
      $newCon = new Database();
      $con = $newCon->connect();
      $assignedToTecnico = "SELECT id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))) as tiempo, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))/COUNT(tecnico_id)) as promedio FROM ticket where id=".$ticketId." ORDER BY tecnico_id DESC";
      $query = $con->query($assignedToTecnico);   
      $row = $query->fetch_row();
      $time= $row[2];
      $timesec= ($time)*60;
      $days = floor($timesec / (60 * 60 * 24));
      $timesec -= $days * (60 * 60 * 24);
      $hours = floor($timesec / (60 * 60));
      $timesec -= $hours * (60 * 60);
      $minutes = floor($timesec / 60);
      $timesec -= $minutes * 60;
      $seconds = floor($timesec);
      $timesec -= $seconds;
      if ($days==0 && $hours==0 && $minutes==0) {
         echo "Aún no se ha visitado a este cliente";
      }else{ 
         echo str_replace ("-","","{$days} dias, {$hours} horas, {$minutes} minutos.");
      }
      ?>
   </td>
   <td>
   <?php echo$user->time_at; ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php
      } else {
          echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>No hay tickets abiertos</p>";
      }
      ?>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Esto me genera una tablita estática muy bonita, con todo lo que debería llevar una sección de monitoreo.

Sin embargo, se me ha solicitado que muestre un cronómetro que se detenga al momento de que el técnico haga check-in en el ticket.

La hora de inicio, se extrae de la base de datos, y ése campo es `time_at`. La hora de check-in es `visit_hour_in`. Ambos campos son varchar, y la hora se registra como, por ejemplo, `14:50`.

Leí [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26050234/11085376) en la que se adjuntó un código propuesto, el siguiente:

```js
var startDateTime = new Date(2019,2,25,0,59,0,0); // (acá debería imprimir `time_at`) El formato de esto es YYYY (M-1) D H m s ms, cuando lo que tengo en la base de datos solo es H:m
var startStamp = startDateTime.getTime();
var newDate = new Date();
var newStamp = newDate.getTime();

var timer; 

function updateClock() {
    newDate = new Date();
    newStamp = newDate.getTime();
    var diff = Math.round((newStamp-startStamp)/1000);
    
    var d = Math.floor(diff/(24*60*60)); 
    diff = diff-(d*24*60*60);
    var h = Math.floor(diff/(60*60));
    diff = diff-(h*60*60);
    var m = Math.floor(diff/(60));
    diff = diff-(m*60);
    var s = diff;
    
    document.getElementById("time-elapsed").innerHTML = d+" dia(s), "+h+" hora(s), "+m+" minuto(s), "+s+" segundo(s)";
}

timer = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time-elapsed"></div>
```

El problema de este código es que solo se ejecutará en el div con la id `time-elapsed`, y que el número de mes inicial, enero, tiene que ser cero.

¿Cómo puedo adaptar ése código para que ejecute el cronómetro propuesto?